# Rails 4 upgrade production nginx issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, nginx, asset-pipeline

I've recently updated our application from 3 to 4.2.7 and now we're having issues on production environment:

1. Assets are being served as text/html instead of their respective css/js headers.
2. (could be related) Precompiled assets in subdirectories could not be found, meaning `/cssfile.css` is loaded successfully, while `/subdir/cssfile.css` is not.

There were no changes in nginx config files during the upgrade. The changes in config/environment/production.rb are the following:

```
+ config.eager_load = true
-  config.serve_static_assets = false
+  config.serve_static_files = false
-  config.assets.compress = true
+  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
+  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

On deployment the `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass` caused problems so I removed it and precompilation successfully finished, not sure why that happened, since I've read somewhere that in Rails 4 the default css_compressor is :sass.

Here's the nginx config used on the site:

```
upstream SITENAME {
  server unix:/home/deploy/SITENAME/shared/pids/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name production.SITENAMEart.com;
  root /home/deploy/SITENAME/current/public;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/SITENAME.access.log  main;

  client_max_body_size 64M;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /home/deploy/SITENAME/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri @SITENAME;
  }

  location @SITENAME {
    include proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://SITENAME;
  }

  # stats url
  location /nginx_stats {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    #allow SOME.IP.ADD.RESS;
    #deny all;
  }

}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name production.SITENAMEart.com;
  root /home/deploy/SITENAME/current/public;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/SITENAME.access.log  main;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate         /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/wildcard.SITENAMEart.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key     /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/wildcard.SITENAMEart.com.key.unsecure;
  ssl_client_certificate  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/geotrust.crt;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri @SITENAME;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  location @SITENAME {
    include proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://SITENAME;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  # stats url
  location /nginx_stats {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
  }

}
```

What surprises me the most is that the release was thoroughly tested on staging before deploying to production and it has the nginx config - no issues appeared there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. It was related to a custom symlink script I ported from Capistrano v2, the script deleted the contents of public/assets directory after assets were generated.

I'm yet to find out why this wasn't an issue on our staging server though.